# Can you pass your code directly into gcc? For example: gcc -? 'int main(){return 0;}'

Tags: gcc, compilation, g++, system, command-line-arguments

Can you pass your code directly into gcc? If so what is the command line option for it?

For example:

```
g++ -? 'int main(){return 0;}'
```

I need to know because I am using a system command and I rather not make files:

```
system("g++ -C "+code_string+" -o run.out");
```

Basile Starynkevitch solution worked, however I am getting compile errors when I use newlines:

```
echo '#include\nint main(){printf("Hello World"); return 0;}' | g++ -x c++ -Wall -o myprog /dev/stdin
```

Edit: fixed it

```
echo -e '#include\nint main(){printf("Hello World"); return 0;}' | g++ -x c++ -Wall -o myprog /dev/stdin
```

Comment: On which operating system and which version of GCC?

Comment: Why are you asking? What it the motivation? I could improve my answer if I knew it. So please *edit your question*

Comment: I am using gcc 4.8.4 and ubuntu 14.04.

I want to be able to compile code within a program, but I don't want to check for an unused file name, create a file, run command, and then delete the file.

Comment: Creating a temporary file is really easy. Removing it later is also easy (e.g. with [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) ...)

Comment: BTW avoid commenting your question. Please **edit your question** to improve it (e.g. for future reference)

Comment: And I am still very curious about your actual motivations. Are you generating some random standalone program, or do you want to generate some plugin code calling functions inside your program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could ask GCC to read from stdin. Read the [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) chapter of its documentation. Use its [`-x` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) with `/dev/stdin`or with `-`:

```
 echo 'int main(){return 0;}' | g++ -x c++ -O -Wall -o myprog /dev/stdin
```

BTW, since `int main(){return 0;}` is a valid C program, you could use

```
 echo 'int main(){return 0;}' | gcc -x c -O -Wall -o myprog -
```

Programatically, you should consider using [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to get a some `FILE*` handle for a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (so `FILE* f = popen("g++ -x c++ -O -Wall -o myprog /dev/stdin", "w");` then check that `f` is not null) and `fprintf` into it then `pclose` it at last. Don't forget to test the status of `pclose`.

However, most of the time spent by GCC is not [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) (use `-ftime-report` [developer option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html) to find out). You often want to ask it to [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (with `-O2 -march=native` or just `-O` for example), and you surely want to ask for all [warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) (with at least `-Wall` and perhaps also `-Wextra`).

If you want to produce some [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) code in `/tmp/someplugin.so` from some emitted C++ code in `/tmp/myemitted.cc` to be [dynamically loaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) on Linux, compile it as [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) into a [shared object dynamic library](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) with e.g.

```
g++ -o /tmp/someplugin.so -fPIC -shared -Wall -O /tmp/myemitted.cc
```

etc.... then use [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) on `/tmp/someplugin.so` with [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) to fetch some loaded symbols. My [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) is doing this.

Since parsing time is negligible, you could instead write C or C++ code in some temporary file (inside `/tmp/` or `/run` which  is often some fast *tmpfs* on most Linux systems, so writing into it does not require disk I/O).

At last, recent GCC (use at least [GCC 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/)) also has [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) (actually libgccjit). You could use it to build some representation of generated code then ask GCC to compile it.

See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218696/why-languages-that-compile-to-c-c-generate-unreadable-cryptic-code/273895#273895) and [that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257868/when-does-it-make-sense-to-compile-my-own-language-to-c-code-first/257873#257873). Read the [C++ dlopen mini howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/) and the [Program Library HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/), and Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

> I rather not make files

Generating a temporary file (see [mkstemp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html) etc... and you practically could also general some random file name under `/tmp/` ending with `.c`, then register its removal with [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) passed some function doing [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)...)  is really quick (but you should build some kind of [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) in memory before emitting C++ or C code from it). And using some `Makefile` to compile the generated code with some [`make` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) has the advantage (for the advanced user) to be able to change compilers or options (by editing that `Makefile` to configure `make`).

So you are IMHO wrong in avoiding temporary files (notice that `gcc` & `g++` are also generating and deleting temporary files, e.g. containing some assembler code). I would suggest on the contrary generating a temporary file (matching `/tmp/mytemp*.cc`) using some random numbers (see [random(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html); don't forget to seed the PRNG with e.g. `srandom(time(NULL));` early in your `main`). It could be as simple as

```
char tmpbuf[80];
bool unique;
do { // in practice, this loop is extremely likely to run once
  snprintf(tmpbuf, sizeof(tmpbuf), "/tmp/mytemp_%lx_p%d.cc", 
           random(), (int)getpid());
  unique = access(tmpbuf, F_OK);
} while (unique);
// here tmpbuf contains a unique temporary file name
```

You coded:

> system("g++ -C "+code_string+" -o run.out");

Beware, `+` is usually not string catenation. You might use [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) or [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) to build strings. Or use in C++ [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). And if you use [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) you should check its return code:

```
char cmdbuf[128];
snprintf(cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), "g++ -Wall -O %s -o run.out", tmpbuf);
fflush(NULL);
if (system(cmdbuf) != 0) {
   fprintf(stderr, "compilation %s failed\n", cmdbuf);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

BTW, your example is wrong (missing `<stdio.h>`); it is C code, not C++ code. It should be

```
echo -e '#include <stdio.h>\nint main(){printf("Hello World"); return 0;}' \
     |  gcc -x c -Wall -O -o myprog -
```

---

<sup>PS. My answer is focused on Linux, but you could adapt it for your OS.</sup>

Comment: A complete aside, but `-mcpu` is deprecated. Use `-mtune` or (preferably) `-march`.

Comment: It worked except for new lines, I updated my post.
echo '#include\nint main(){printf("Hello World"); return 0;}' | g++ -x c++ -Wall -o myprog /dev/stdin

Comment: You can also use `-` rather than `/dev/stdin` (useful for systems that don't have that device): `echo ... | gcc -x c <options> -`