# Writing a script within the program to write and compile the code

Tags: c++, compilation, execute

I want to be able to pass in a string with c++ code, compile, then execute the code in C++ code.

For example:

```
string code = "#include.... int main() {" \
              "std::cout << \"hello, world\" << std::endline;\n";

obj = compile(code);
execute(obj);
```

I would like something like that, my plan was to make a basic scripting language that converts to c++, and then c++ compiles itself and executes.

Comment: This is basically not possible, except that you write a C++ compiler by yourself. Or you call the c++ compiler from your programm.

Comment: In windows, there is active scripting to go that, works with interpreted languages like JavaScript

Comment: If you are in Linux, you can echo your code in a string and pipe it into gcc, for example. Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299086/can-you-pass-your-code-directly-into-gcc-for-example-gcc-int-mainreturn

Comment: And of course you could add an `&& ./<name-of-your-program-executable>` to execute it if the build went OK.

Comment: If the string is, itself, valid c++ code, that's what your compiler is for. How to manipulate content is an OS question, so you really should give the relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

There are different commands to execute on different shells. For example, Unix needs `$ ./program`, PowerShell needs `> ./program` (.exe like), CMD requires nothing (simply `> program`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string c = argv[1];
    std::string fileName = c + ".cpp";

    std::ofstream write(fileName.c_str());
    std::string compile = "";

    const char *program =
        "#include <iostream>\n" \
        "int main(void) {\n" \
        "    std::cout << \"Hello World!\";\n" \
        "    return 0;\n" \
        "}";

    // designed for Windows Command Prompt
    compile = "g++ -o " + c + ' ' + fileName + " && " + c;

    write << program << std::endl;
    write.close();

    system(compile.c_str());
    
    return 0;
}
```