# Using Python subprocess to compile and run a C++ program without files

Tags: python, c++, subprocess, pipe, io-redirection

I am trying to figure out how to run c++ code with Python's subprocess, without the need of a file or creation of a file, just a string.

I was able to get it to run Python code. In Python, it can be done by taking the command

`echo "print('Hello World')" | python3`

and doing the equivalent in Python subprocess with

```
def run_python(self, code):
    file_input = subprocess.run(["echo", code], capture_output=True, timeout=2)
    output = subprocess.run(["python3"], input=file_input.stdout, capture_output=True, timeout=10)
    return output.stdout.decode()
```

For C++, I cannot seem to get an equivalent terminal command working.
I saw online

```
g++ -o main -std=c++11 -O2 -x c++ <<< '#include <iostream>\nint main(){ std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl; return 0; }' && ./main
```

but this gives me the error

```
clang: error: no input files
```

so I am unsure if I am on the right track, and more importantly do not know how to use subprocess to get this to work.

What would be the terminal command and the equivalent subprocess Python function for C++?

Comment: Unlike Python, C++ is a compiler language and therefor uses multiple build steps to actually create the binary. As such, 'running c++ code without creating files' is, to my knowledge, not possible. At the very least the resulting binary will be created. But you could go the extra mile, create a temporary directory, write your source files in there and, sic the compiler on them and, after the binary has been compiled (and run), you can delete the whole thing again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38299134/9296093 This might help you with compiling C without source file, but the resulting binaries will still be created

Comment: Not sure what the objection to writing on disk is? But how about writing the executable on a RAM-based filesystem? https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get

```
 echo 'int main(){return 0;}' | g++ -x c++ -O -Wall -o myprog /dev/stdin | ./myprog
```

with

```
echo_result = subprocess.run(["echo", code], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

gpp_command = ["g++", "-x", "c++", "-O", "-Wall", "-o", "myprog", "/dev/stdin"]
gpp_result = subprocess.run(gpp_command, input=echo_result.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output = subprocess.run(["./myprog"], input=gpp_result.stdout, capture_output=True)
os.remove("myprog")
```

The only problem is although a file does not need to be created to compile, an executable is created in the end. This is the best solution I have come across so far.